# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMFactory.createOMElement(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMDataSource;)Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMSourcedElement;

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-axis, axiom

I am developer at Capgemini and I have an issue with a Java EE application that I am developing.

I am calling a webservice with `Axis2` in a junit test in a project and it works. But when I call the same method in an other project that refers to the first (with maven dependencies) and I launch my application I have the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMFactory.createOMElement(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMDataSource;)Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMSourcedElement;
```

Does anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong?

If you need more information ask me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The error means that the second project runs with a version of the Axiom library that is older than the version expected by the first project. There are two possible reasons for that:

- The runtime environment in which you deploy the second project has its own version of Axiom. That would e.g. be the case for a Java EE application deployed on WebSphere.
- The second project has another (direct or indirect) dependency on the Axiom library with a different version as the first project, and Maven selects that version. You should be able to see that when you execute `mvn dependency:tree` on the second project. If that's the case, add a `dependencyManagement` section to the POM to force it to use the right version.